# What is wrong with my syntax for this binary tree search function in ML?

Tags: syntax, binary-search-tree, ml

I am trying to create a function in ML that searches through a binary tree for a value and returns true or false. Can anyone help me fix my function syntactically so that it works? Here is what I have:

```
datatype either = ImAString of string | ImAnInt of int;
datatype eitherTree = LEAF of either | NODE of eitherTree*either*eitherTree;
fun eitherSearch(LEAF(ImAnInt x), search_value) = (x=search_value)
|  eitherSearch(LEAF(ImAString x), search_value) = false
|  eitherSearch(NODE(left, ImAString node_value, right), search_value) = false
|  eitherSearch(NODE(left, ImAnInt node_value, right), search_value) =
  if (search_value > node_value)
  then eitherSearch(right, search_value)
  else eitherSearch(left, search_value);
```

Comment: What syntax error are you getting?

Comment: Warning-Matches are not exhaustive.
Found near
  fun
     eitherSearch (... ..., ...) = (x = search_value) |
        eitherSearch (...) = false |
        eitherSearch ... = if ... then ... else ...
val eitherSearch = fn: eitherTree * int -> bool

Comment: You don't have a clause for the `NODE(_, ImAString _, _)` case.

Comment: How does it look now?

Comment: Better - does it fix the exhaustiveness problem?